# Listing my past reviews

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

Is there a way to check history of my reviews?

I would like to go trough my reviews (and especially those that I reviewed differently than *the community*) to see where my opinions differ with others; for example I tend to mark "*code only answers*" as *Looks OK* and I would like to know how others perceive it.

I was clicking trough the site and was unable to find anything like this. Is there something like this implemented already? Should it be?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/1149736/vyktor?tab=activity&sort=reviews) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Technically speaking; the other questions/answers doesn't answer the "list audits with different results than my review".